# Drag behaviour dropped on useGesture

Tags: reactjs, gesture, react-use-gesture

I'm using react-use-gesture to drag a div along the x-axis. It doesn't do anything fancy, just store the movement `x` value and use that to offset the `left` css property of the div. The code uses the `useState` hook to store the cumulative x-offset and the setting of the state triggers the re-render.

Example here: https://3upld.csb.app/ (https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-usegesture-test-forked-3upld?file=/src/index.js&codemirror=1)

Code below

```
export default function Home() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);

  const bind = useGesture(
    {
      onDrag: ({ movement: [mx] }) => {
        console.log("x", mx);
        setOffset(mx);
      }
    },
    {
      drag: {
        initial: () => [offset, 0]
      }
    }
  );
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="font-bold text-3xl">React useGesture test</h1>
      <div className="relative">
        <div
          {...bind()}
          className="absolute bg-red-600 h-48 w-48"
          style={{ left: `${100 + offset}px` }}
        >
          Box
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I view this browser, it works great - I can drag around.
When I switch the browser to emulation it won't drag for more than a few pixels. See example gif below.

[image]

I've tested this also on Chrome on an Android phone (exhibits the problem) and Safari on an iPad Pro (does *not* exhibit the problem if I drag slowly).

Does anyone know why this isn't working smoothly on mobile? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try setting `touch-action: none;` in the css.
https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/extras/